# How to automatically open a popup imageview

Tags: android, listview, popup

I have this code for now

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_serviciosp);

    final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openpopup);
        btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                        = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                        popupView,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                Button btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
                btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 50, -30);

            }
        });

    CustomList adapter = new CustomList(Agro.this, web, desc, tel, imageId, imageId3);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvlista);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Agro.this, "Usted Clico en " + web[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (position == 0) {

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:22222222222222"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }


        }
    });
}
```

what it does is show a button above my listview, when i press the button it show the popup , but what i wanna do is that when i wait like 3 or 4 seconds after o joined to the list it popup automatically without a button press.

Also i wanna know how to randomize the auto pop up , so it pop us eventually and not each time i enter to the layout.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For opening pop up after 4 seconds  you can use the below code in your onCreate

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            btnOpenPopup.performClick();
         }, 4000);
```

What it does is it simulates button click after 4 seconds of starting the activity.

In case you dont want to auto pop up if user already clicked button you can have a global boolean - userClicked. Uf user clicks set the boolean to true otherwise initially let it be false. In that case the above method can be changed as

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!userClicked)
              btnOpenPopup.performClick();
         }, 4000);
```

And for randomising just use a random generator and get an int between 1 to 5. If int is 1 then show, otherwise dont. YOu can do as below.

```
    Random random = new Random();
     int x= random.nextInt(5)+1;
```

ANd inside the handler method your if statement should change as

```
      if(!userClicked && x==1)
            btnOpenPopup.performClick();
```

SO your code will change as

```
   prvate boolean userClicked = false;

     @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.content_serviciosp);

final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openpopup);
    btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            userClicked=true;
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                    = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    popupView,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            Button btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
            btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });

            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 50, -30);

        }
    });

     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
           Random random = new Random();
           int x= random.nextInt(5)+1;
            if(!userClicked && x==1)
              btnOpenPopup.performClick();
         }}, 4000);

    ........
```

Comment: And by randomize what do you mean? Open popup once in 2 or 3 times the layout opens?

Comment: yes @Ragesh Ramesh , yeah, lets say i open the same layout 10 times but it will randomly pop up in certain ones, not every time i enter in the layout

Comment: I have edited the answer. Have a look. See if it works to your liking and let me know.

Comment: Thanks so much ragesh , can you please implement the code you send to me to the code i post in the question, im a little bit confused where to add this , thanks.

Comment: when i add the handler below my oncreate section , i got a little errors, i imported the necesary class, but i cant get it to work as i like.

Comment: did you import import android.os.Handler;

Comment: new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Random random = new Random();
                int x= random.nextInt(5)+1;
                if(!userClicked && x==1)
                    btnOpenPopup.performClick();
            }, 4000);

i think here is missing an  }  . i get unexpected token in 4000

Comment: yes i imported the os.handler already and im keep getting an error in the handler part

Comment: I edited. I just left out a } before ,4000. Check now